# Is there a way to create a WAFv2 from a Terraform script

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-waf

I managed to build a WAF(v1) infrastructure component on AWS using a Terraform script.  Since November 2019, AWS recommends to use a WAFv2 instead, but I don't see how to script this one using Terraform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not supported by terraform yet. However, if you really want to use terraform, I have built a module which uses cloudformation resource to deploy wafv2. You can find it -> https://github.com/umotif-public/terraform-aws-waf-webaclv2

It is published to terraform registry so you can source it from there.

Answer (score 6):

Sure, here is an example of the resource for the WAFv2 with a rate limit example rule and the association with an ALB:

```
resource "aws_wafv2_web_acl" "my_web_acl" {
  name  = "my-web-acl"
  scope = "REGIONAL"

  default_action {
    allow {}
  }

  rule {
    name     = "RateLimit"
    priority = 1

    action {
      block {}
    }

    statement {

      rate_based_statement {
        aggregate_key_type = "IP"
        limit              = 500
      }
    }

    visibility_config {
      cloudwatch_metrics_enabled = true
      metric_name                = "RateLimit"
      sampled_requests_enabled   = true
    }
  }

  visibility_config {
    cloudwatch_metrics_enabled = false
    metric_name                = "my-web-acl"
    sampled_requests_enabled   = false
  }
}

resource "aws_wafv2_web_acl_association" "web_acl_association_my_lb" {
  resource_arn = aws_lb.my_lb.arn
  web_acl_arn  = aws_wafv2_web_acl.my_web_acl.arn
}
```